# Control flow graphs generation for Java Codes

Tags: java, testing, dot, control-flow-graph

I'm making a Tool to generate and Visualize Control Flow Graphs from Java Source codes

I'm making a Project that will read a Java source code line by line , then generate Control flow graph of the code and then visualize it. But I'm not sure how to do that, my teacher has told me to learn DOT to do this process but I'm confused.

Can someone please tell me the steps and the way to achieve my the goal I've just described?

Comment: [DOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) is a graph description language.  It would be a reasonable format for the output of your code analysis.  Overall, however, "please tell me the steps ..." is far too broad a question for SO, especially given the relatively ambitious project you've described.

Comment: Oh no no....I know the steps involved . I guess I wrote it the wrong way . I meant to ask the main steps for basic cfg visualization using DOT.